# Can I use BAT and GND pads for wiring BetaFPV SMO4K?

Tags: flight-controller, first-person-view, camera, wiring, iflight

I'm trying to wire [BetaFPV SMO4K](https://betafpv.com/products/smo-4k-camera?variant=39758238843014) camera to my IFlight Evoque F5D which uses [BLITZ F7 Stack (F7 V1.1 + 55A 4in1 ESC) stack](https://shop.iflight-rc.com/quad-parts-cat20/electronics-cat27/BLITZ?product_id=1695). Official SMO4K manual suggests connecting camera power cable to `VBAT` and `GND` which is usually located on ESC:
[image: SMO4k wiring power]
BLITZ E55 ESC does not provide additional `VBAT` and `GND` pads for soldering camera power cable, but on F7 controller there are `BAT` and `GND` pads:

[image: F7 diagram]
**Question**:
So can I use those `BAT` and `GND` pads for powering SMO4K camera? What's the difference between `BAT` and `VBAT` on FC?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `BAT` might be a voltage sensing input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, go ahead. That pad is connected to VBAT and will provide power to the camera. Do not exceed 6S however that's irrelevant since none of the other components are rated above 6S.

## Long answer

The FC needs to get power from somewhere. In this case (in a stack where the manufacturer controls both sides of the 10-pin connector), VBAT comes from the ESC to the FC through the 10 pin cable that connects the two.

If you weren't using an integrated stack, then VBAT would have to be provided to the FC. It's a little strange given that they have two pins in the 10-pin connector to add a third solderable pad, but it's a convenience that you're going to use, so I wouldn't say it's a bad thing.

You can triple check this by connecting the ESC and FC via the provided cable, and use a multimeter in diode check (beep test) mode to confirm that pad is indeed connected to the main battery input.

### What's the difference between BAT and VBAT?

Arguably, nothing. There's no predefined standard here and the terminology is just whatever the mfg feels like using at the time. You would think a set of FC/ESC would share terminology, but I guess they wanted to be unique.